# How do I simply transfer and download a file from an FTP server with Python?

Tags: python, ftp

I've noticed that the FTP library doesn't seem to have a method or function of straight up downloading a file from an FTP server. The only function I've come across for downloading a file is `ftp.retrbinary` and in order to transfer the file contents, you essentially have to write the contents to a pre-existing file on the local computer where the Python script is located.

Is there a way to download the file as-is without having to create a local file first?

Edit: I think the better question to ask is: do I need to have a pre-existing file in order to download an FTP server file's contents?

Comment: Take at look at the stdlib ftplib - https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: Yep, I'm using `ftp.retrbinary` from that library. Just wondering if this method or function doesn't need a pre-existing file

Comment: By 'straight-up', do you mean download into memory?

Comment: Here's a conversation that might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696413/ftp-retrbinary-help-python

Answer (score 0):

To download a file from FTP this code will do the job

`import urllib urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file') # if you need to pass credentials: # urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file', 'file')`